# Zero-filling file and deleting from disk in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a secure deletion feature to my app and the idea is to zero-fill the file before actually deleting it. The way I approached this is by writing in 10 MB chunks (or thereabouts). However, the performance is unacceptable for large files. For example, it takes about 300 seconds to zerofill a 10 GB file on an iPhone XS.

I played around with the chunk size but I didn't see much change.

This is my implementation:

```
/// Opens a file handle to the given path and zero-fills the file.
/// - Parameter path: File path
/// - Returns: True if successful, false if an error was encountered.
@discardableResult public func zeroFillFile(at path: String) -> Bool {

    guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: path) else {
        return false
    }
    defer {
        do {
            try fileHandle.close()
        }
        catch {
            print("Error while closing file handle at \(path): \(error)")
        }
    }

    let chunkSize: Int = 1_000_000 * 10 // 10 MB
    let zeroData = Data(count: chunkSize)

    let total = FileManager.default.fileSize(for: path) ?? 0
    var written: Int64 = 0

    while written < total {
        let toWrite = min(Int64(chunkSize), total - written)
        do {
            var data = zeroData
            if chunkSize != toWrite {
                data = zeroData.subdata(in: zeroData.startIndex..<zeroData.startIndex.advanced(by: Int(toWrite)))
            }
            try fileHandle.write(contentsOf: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error while zerofilling file at \(path): \(error)")
            return false
        }
        written += toWrite
    }

    return true
}
```

I am wondering, is there a better way to approach this or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely useless. The SSD firmware will decide where to write that data and you have ZERO control over that. So you will just be writing your zeros somewhere else on the SSD while the original data will be overwritten later.. much later ... If the device has data protection on. (eg has a pin at least) there should be no security problem as the data is encrypted.

Comment: I understand that this feature is absolutely useless for >99.999% of the iPhone users out there. However, the users that need this require a way to completely and definitively remove that data in such a way it is completely irrecoverable even considering an unlocked device with direct disk access at the OS level. Do you have any documentation on "you will just be writing your zeros somewhere else on the SSD while the original data will be overwritten later.. much later"?

Comment: No, it is useless for 100% of users because it doesn't overwrite the data because of [wear levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling). If you really want to provide secure destruction you need to 1) create a unique key in the keychain 2) encrypt the file with the key 3) use the key to decrypt the file as required 4) delete the key when you delete the file. The ios Secure Enclave ensures that keys really are destroyed, but whole device encryption will probably be fine unless you are dealing with highly resourced state level actors